# Quotient algebras of nilpotent Lie algebra are nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, quotient-spaces, nilpotence

For the following proposition I found a proof in some notes that I don't understand. Below definition 1 defines the terminology I'm using, and proof attempt 1 gives my attempt at the proposition. Proof attempt 2 is from the notes (which are not available online), and my question is the following:

How does Proof 2 make sense? Could it be that they use another definition of quotient algebras?

**Proposition**: Let $g$ be a nilpotent Lie algebra, and let $h\lhd g$ be an ideal of $g$. Then the quotient Lie algebra $g/h$ is also nilpotent.

**Definition 1**: Let $(g, [\cdot,\cdot])$ be a Lie algebra, and $h\lhd g$ be an ideal of $g$. Then we define the quotient Lie algebra $(g/h, [\cdot, \cdot]_q)$ to be the quotient vector space with Lie bracket given by 
$$[\alpha+h,\beta+h]_q=[\alpha,\beta]+h.$$

**Proof attempt 1** Suppose $g$ is nilpotent, $h\lhd g$. Then $C^N(g) = \{0\}$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$. Observe that $C^0(g/h) \subset \{\alpha+h:\ \alpha\in C^0(g)\}$, and by induction $C^n(g/h) \subset \{\alpha + h:\ \alpha \in C^n(g)\}$. It follows that $C^N(g/h) = \{0+h\}$. $\square$

**Proof attempt 2**: Suppose $g$ is nilpotent, $h\lhd g$. An easy induction shows that if $h$ is an ideal, then $C^n(g/h) = (C^n(g) + h)/h$, and so again if $C^N(g) = 0$ we must also have $C^N(g/h) = 0$

*My difficulty* is with interpreting the expression $C^n(g/h) = (C^n(g) + h)/h$, it seems erroneous to me... What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative way to formulate the second attempt. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a nilpotent Lie algebra, and $\pi\colon \mathfrak{g}\rightarrow L$ a surjective Lie algebra homomorphism. Then $\pi(\mathfrak{g}^n)=L^n$, so that $L$ is nilpotent as well. Now chose $L=\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}$ and $\pi\colon \mathfrak{g}\rightarrow \mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}$ the canonical surjection.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this is a neat approach. My question however is not asking for alternatives, I’d like to establish if my understanding of Proof 2 above is correct, ie that that proof makes no sense. Do you have a thought on this?

Comment: In the second proof the claim about $(\mathfrak{g/h})^n$ is just what I wrote in terms of the canonical surjection $\pi$ above. So this is more or less the same.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde if $I\subset L$ a nilpotent ideal and $L/I$ nilpotent then $L$ is a nilpotent lie-algebra? I think it is true, if I look at the canonical homomorphism $\pi: L \to L/I$  and do similar argument.

Comment: @user726608 No, this is not true in general. Let $L=\mathfrak{r}_2(F)$ be the non-abelian Lie algebra of dimension $2$ over $F$.